# Solving mathjax & ckeditor display maths

Tags: ckeditor, mathjax

Am using mathjax to show some maths questions on aspx page which works fine, but if I add ckeditor to the same page the maths questions compresses together and the maths format is incorrect.

Am lost on how to fix this, has anyone come across this before?

Code I have up to now is:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">



MathJax.Hub.Config({
showProcessingMessages: false,
tex2jax: { inlineMath: [['$','$'],['\\(','\\)']] },
extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
jax: ["input/TeX","output/HTML-CSS"],
"HTML-CSS": {
  availableFonts:[], preferredFont: null, webFont: null,
  styles: {".MathJax_Preview": {visibility: "hidden"}}
}
```

});

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - you have problem with running MathJax on one page with CKEditor? Or inside CKEditor?

Comment: I too have similar problem. It is running Mathjax inside CKEditor.